# In the Go select construct, can I have send and receive to unbuffered channel in two case statements?

Tags: go

I am expecting this code to go in an infinite loop, sending and receiving the message. But it does not seem to either send or receive. Why?

```
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case ch1 <- 1:
            println("sent 1 ")
        case c := <-ch1:
            println(" received ", c)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [channel documentation says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types):

> If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready.

The [select documentation says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.

The receive case cannot proceed because there's not a ready sender.  The send case cannot proceed because there's not a ready receiver.  The program deadlocks in the select.

A single goroutine cannot make the send and receive both ready because the goroutine can only execute one branch of the select at a time.

The program will loop forever if the channel is buffered ([playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/YN5KYhQaes)).

Comment: Why isn't this statement : "case c := <-ch1:" enough to trigger the fact that receiver is ready? And this statement "case ch1 <- 1:" enough to trigger that sender is ready?
It seems to be enough, when two separate go-routines are running it, like below example suggested by @A-R

Comment: A single goroutine cannot make the send and receive both ready because the goroutine can only execute one branch of the select at a time.

Answer (score 3):

To unbuffered channel with one goroutine: **No** (Why: **by design**):
You may use **Buffered channel with one goroutine** or
**two goroutines using unbuffered channel** to avoid **deadlock**:

> If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has
>   received the value. If the channel has a buffer, the sender blocks
>   only until the value has been copied to the buffer; if the buffer is
>   full, this means waiting until some receiver has retrieved a value.

---

1- Using **buffered channel**: The `main` itself is a **goroutine** and if you need do it in one goroutine you should use buffered channel like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 1)
    for {
        select {
        case ch1 <- 1:
            fmt.Println("sent 1 ")
        case c := <-ch1:
            fmt.Println(" received ", c)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

output:

```
sent 1
 received  1
sent 1
 received  1
sent 1
 received  1
```

---

2- Using **unbuffered channel**: You may send and receive to unbuffered channel in two `case` statements in one `select`, and you need **two goroutines** here, see:

Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Ru5WdOsA3q):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go ct("Alex")
    go ct("John")
    //select {}
    time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
}
func ct(name string) {
    for {
        select {
        case ch1 <- 1:
            fmt.Println(name, "sent 1")
        case c := <-ch1:
            fmt.Println(name, "received:", c)
        }
        fmt.Println(name, "waiting...")
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

var ch1 = make(chan int)
```

output:

```
John sent 1
John waiting...
Alex received: 1
Alex waiting...
John received: 1
John waiting...
Alex sent 1
Alex waiting...
John sent 1
John waiting...
Alex received: 1
Alex waiting...
```

Comment: I meant why can't I do it using a single go routine as above.

Comment: @A-R - thanks for the edit, but really - I am not trying to get it working - I am trying to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Why isn't this statement : "case c := <-ch1:" enough to trigger the fact that receiver is ready? And this statement "case ch1 <- 1:" enough to trigger that sender is ready? It seems to be enough, when two separate go-routines are running it, like you suggested

Comment: it is by design, and this is good, in many situations we need unbuffered channels to make direct handshaking. when we need to send a data to another channel without direct handshaking we may use buffered channel so we don't care what time the other party receives data, in your code this code runs first: `case ch1 <- 1` and it needs handshaking so simply use buffered channel then we are good to Go! in `select ` all `case` statements run once from top down, not concurrently: try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/-yqnFMUcBE)