# Sending value to a channel is not ready in the select

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("func at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
        select {
        case ch <- 1:
            fmt.Println("running send")
        default:
            fmt.Println("running default")
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("main at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

[the playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/bwL2TXRYWR8)

I have researched for a day but still cannot explain why `case ch <- 1:` is not ready, and the default case is selected to run. Of course, it causes deadlock!

Comment: f you're waiting for a value that may come later, why do you have a `default` case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [doc](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels):

> If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value. If the channel has a buffer, the sender blocks only until the value has been copied to the buffer; if the buffer is full, this means waiting until some receiver has retrieved a value.

One way is to use this. Here's the receiver goroutine is spawned first. Also, if the receiver is not ready yet, default case will be picked up. And if it's ready, the specific case will be ready. If you run this several times, you can see either of cases happening.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    // goroutine acts as the reciever
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("main at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }()
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("func at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
        select {
        case ch <- 1:
            fmt.Println("running send")
        default:
            fmt.Println("running default")
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // Wait for the goroutines
}
```

Another solution would be to use, buffered channel:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int, 1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("func at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
        select {
        case ch <- 1:
            fmt.Println("running send")
        default:
            fmt.Println("running default")
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("main at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Also, do read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660533/why-does-the-use-of-an-unbuffered-channel-in-the-same-goroutine-result-in-a-dead) on stackoverflow

Comment: As I understand your answer, both `case ch <- 1` and `default:` is ready, select pick `default:` randomly. That's why `fmt.Println(<-ch)` causes deadlock. Is it you meaning?

Comment: Yes and no. Point is in your code `case ch <- 1` doesn't get ready because of the explanation I gave related to unbuffered channel. And yes, selection of default and use of `fmt.Println(<-ch)`  creates a deadlock state.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please have a look. And run the first program several times to see both cases. You'll understand how the spawning of goroutines matters.

Comment: As you said, I try to sleep a lit bit before `fmt.Printf("main at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())` => running default first, then `fmt.Printf("func at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())` => running send. Your explanation is true. I wonder why `case ch <- 1` is not ready. I though it's always ready because no other senders block it.

Comment: Actually, my question come from [Go Concurrency Patterns: Timing out, moving on](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-timeouts) in the Query function. The author mention "_However, if the result arrives before the main function has made it to the receive, the send could fail since no one is ready_". I cannot find out why

Comment: See, your channel is unbuffered which means if the sender sends into the channel, there's no buffer to store it and hence there should be a receiver ready. Having a buffered channel will guarantee that its channel has some buffer to store it.

So, the send could fail since no one is ready means that if the result arrives before the main goroutine has made it to the receive, the send could fail.

Comment: Read this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47525732/5821408

Comment: Your first example does not guarantee anything, as there no coordination ensuring the value is sent before the select statement. Maybe that's the case you were trying to show, but it does not make for a correct answer.

Comment: As I know, the send channel is ready when the is a receiver is waiting to receive the value, the receive channel is ready when the is a send channel is sending to it and waiting the sent value to be receive. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You have created the Go channel with make(chan int) which is not buffered. You need a buffered channel (that won't necessarily block), you should use make(chan int, 20) where 20 is the size of the channel

The thing about unbuffered channels is that they are also synchronous, so they always block on write as well as read. The same thing can happen to buffered channels when the buffer fills up.

Try below code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int, 20)
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("func at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
        select {
        case ch <- 1:
            fmt.Println("running send")
        default:
            fmt.Println("running default")
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("main at %d\n", time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a lit bit more. I know buffered channel can solve the issue, I also know locking technique for buffered and unbuffered channel. But, I cannot explain what happens here.